# How do I make a new div with a specific Id + n?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, loops

I've got a button and when it's pushed this code launches:

> var nrDivs = "1"
>   var neuDiv = document.createElement("div");
>       neuDiv.setAttribute("Id","theDiv" + nrDivs);
>       neuDiv.innerHTML = "Text";
>       $('#allDivs').append(neuDiv);
>
> newfeed.draw(neuDiv);

I know that right now the script creates a new div with the ID: theDiv1.
What I'm trying to do is when I click the button a second time, it creates a div with the ID: theDiv2.

Each time the user presses the button there should be a new div drawn and I'm trying to target that new div and insert dynamic text.

Thanks, Noor

Comment: Do your divs need an ID?  There's often a relative way to find them, making this a non-issue, if it's an option.

Comment: I'm having each div load new content, to do that I needed them to have different IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more jQuery you could use here, but I kept it pretty much the same as yours, adding only enough to do what you wanted.

Please note that this will count ALL `div` elements within `#allDivs`. If there are some that you don't wish to count, another approach must be taken.

```
$(document.ready(function() {

    $('#myButton').click(function() {     // On page load, assign click event handler to your button

        var nrDivs = $('div', '#allDivs').length + 1;    // Retrieve all 'div' elements within '#allDivs', and get its length plus 1
        var neuDiv = document.createElement("div");
        neuDiv.setAttribute("Id","theDiv" + nrDivs);
        neuDiv.innerHTML = "Text";
        $('#allDivs').append(neuDiv);
        newfeed.draw(neuDiv);

    });

});
```

---

**EDIT:**

A more jQuery-like way:

```
$(document.ready(function() {

    $('#myButton').click(function() {     // On page load, assign click event handler to your button

        var nrDivs = $('div', '#allDivs').length + 1;    // Retrieve all 'div' elements within '#allDivs', and get its length plus 1
        var $neuDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','theDiv' + nrDivs)
                                .text("Text")
                                .appendTo('#allDivs');
        newfeed.draw(neuDiv);

    });

});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Selectors in jQuery are very powerful and offer lots of flexibility.

For example, the line above that gets all the `div` elements under `#allDivs` could be re-written as:

```
$('#allDivs div').length + 1;
```

... which is exactly the same.

If you only want to get the `div` elements that are immediate children of `#allDivs`, use:

```
$('#allDivs > div').length + 1;
```

or

```
$('#allDivs').children('div').length + 1;
```

Another alternative would be to give these `div` elements a special class that you can use as a selector. So, for example, when you create a new `div` to add to `#allDivs`, do it this way:

```
var $neuDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','theDiv' + nrDivs)
                                .addClass('topDiv')
                                .text("Text")
                                .appendTo('#allDivs');
```

Now the top `div` elements in `#allDivs` will have a class called `topDiv', and you can reference that in your selector like this:

```
$('#allDivs .topDiv').length + 1;
```

...which will only return `div` elements that have the class `topDiv`.

This only scratches the surface of what you can do with selectors in jQuery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's a bit faster way in 1.4 :) `$('<div />', { 'id':'theDiv' + nrDivs, text:"Text" }).appendTo('#allDivs')`

Comment: @Nick. Very nice. I've seen it but forget to use it. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm still learning and you guys are great teachers. This worked is all I needed + more, which is a good thing :)!

Comment: @patrick & nick Is it possible to not include the children of each Div inside allDivs? Reason is that when I call the function it creates theDiv(s) and places divs inside those..

Comment: Rather than .text("Text"), you might want to use .html("Text").

Comment: There are a couple of ways to accomplish that. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Looking at your comment again, I'm not sure if my update addresses your concern. If you're having some other issue, let me know. If you need to clear the content of a `div`, you can use jQuery's `.empty()` function.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could make nDivs a global variable and increment it each time you create a div.

You could also use a jquery selector to get all of the divs and then use length to get a count, to which you can add one for your new div.

Answer (score 0):

To add new ID to div do this.

By deafult it's var nrDivs = "1"
On click do : n++;

Answer (score 0):

Either name nDivs a global variable (bad to use globals in general, but it works), and increment it each time this code runs.

Or better yet, make this code a [closure](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html), able to access nDivs